# I want to do an online radio with Python

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, streaming

I want to make an online radio streaming available in my web page which is made with Django, (I already have video, I know that this is not a radio).

I would like to stream radio from the page and then use the Facebook APIs and twitch to transmit at the same time.

what Python libraries should I use to do the streaming?

Comment: Did my answer work for you @ulysss316?

Answer (score 0):

Using [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/);

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, blocksize=1024, chunks=-1):
    """Lazy function (generator) to read a file piece by piece.
    Default chunk size: 1k."""
    while chunks:
        data = file_object.read(blocksize)
        if not data:
            break
         yield data
         chunks -= 1

requests.post('http://some.url/chunked', data=read_in_chunks(f))
```